# VSCode language server php improper validation

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, ssh, vscode-remote

I have a project setup at AWS, and I do make changes on the server via VS Code ssh-remote connection.
Now the problem is php version installed there is 7.0.18 and when I opened the code in VS it shows error that

> The language server needs at least php7.1 installed. Version
> found:7.0.18

Now when I search the solutions for it they all said download php and change settings.json to include
php.executablepath = "path to php"

now if I add path to php as /usr/bin/php7.4 it still shows the same error, and I guess it searches in remote computer not in local computer.

What can I do, if I can't upgrade any version on remote system.

Comment: _"if I can't upgrade any version on remote system"_ - Then you have a bigger issue since both 7.0 and 7.1 are unsupported (they are not even getting security updates anymore). You should upgrade both the server and your local version.

Comment: okay. Thanks for your response. But isn't it possible to use php from local system for validating php in vscode.